# Wix Toolset Output naming

Tags: wix

I have the following in my Wix project file. It produces an installer called prog.1.12.123.1234.msi. This is close to what I want but not quite. What I need is for the file to be named prog.1.12.123.msi with the revision number excluded. Is there an easy way to do this or must I write a custom file renamer and then call it using an msbuild EXEC task ?

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="C:\prog.exe">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Copy SourceFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName).msi" DestinationFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName)_%(AssemblyVersion.Version).msi" />
    <Delete Files=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName).msi" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoever wrote DOS must have been smoking something. The simplest solution was a rather complex DOS rename:

```
    <Exec Command="cd .\bin\$(Configuration) %26 del ????????????????????.??????????.??????????.msi %26 ren ????????????????????.??????????.??????????.??????????.msi ????????????????????.??????????.??????????.msi"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you kidding me?

Comment: No. This was used for a commercial product. So it's very serious business. Do you know a simpler way ? Anyway my eventual solution was more complex involving GetAssemblyIdentiy etc because I needed to use the 3 part version number inside .wxs as well as in msbuild.